# Multiple aliases for a Sybase table?

Tags: alias, sybase

I am working on a team trying to phase out a legacy system. As this is a rather large system with multiple integrations, the database will live on, even after the legacy system is replaced.

Now, the problem is that all the table names in the database have numerical names: "RT001", "RT002", "RT003", etc. With well over 100 tables it gets harder to know what each table is, and how can be joined to get hold of specific data.

Is there a way to define a global table alias in sybase so that sybase knows that the SQL"select * from Order, OrderItems where ..." is referring to tables RT035 and RT036 ? This way I can keep the original table names as RT035, while having an alias like "Order", or even "RT035_Order" refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing as a "synonym" (that's what it's called in an Oracle database) in Sybase ASE. But you could still use simple view to do basically the same thing:

```
CREATE VIEW Order AS SELECT * FROM RT035;
```

Comment: Will this view then update with whatever changes that occur on the table it has created the view from ?

Comment: I am asking because, it seems that when my view is created, that the * in the select is replaced with the column-names that is currently in the RT035 table.

Comment: Not exactly. The view will use "select * from ...". But if you modify any of the tables columns the view won't refelect these changes without some extra work. Take a look at the stored procedure "sp_refreshview", this should do the job. You will have to call that any time you modify the table.